# NSProgressIndicator disappears whenever it starts animating

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I have an NSProgressIndicator (spinning) that displays fine when it is not animating, but as soon as it starts animating it disappears. However, when I switch the style to a progress bar, it displays just fine, animations and all. Additionally, it reappears when it stops animating, so it is only invisible while it is spinning.

I am new to Cocoa programming, and I have been searching for several hours through my code and online trying to figure out my issue, but I have been unsuccessful. What would cause this issue?

My code is somewhat based on the code from Apple's sample AVSimplePlayer, found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011060).

Comment: Are you calling startAnimation on thread?

Comment: When the view is initialized, I call [progressIndicator startAnimation:nil]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem today. It turns out that when using `spin`, the other things that are running in main thread run first. That means, if you have

```
let progressIndicator // 
progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
// do tasks
progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
```

The order in reality is

```
let progressIndicator // 
// do tasks
progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
```

So you never see the animation. Here is the workaround, stop main runloop a little while, after `progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)`.

```
let progressIndicator // 
progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.001))
// do tasks
progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
```

Then everything will be fine. I find this answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/99164). You can also try other answers there too.

Comment: For me, this makes it not disappear, but it still doesn't animate. :(